# pandas count values using external list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['s1'] = ['n', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'n', 't', 't']
df['s2'] = ['n', 'n', 'u', 'u', 'n', 't', 't']
df['s3'] = ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']
df['s4'] = ['u', 'u', 'u', 'u', 'n', 't', 't']
```

and I try to obtain a dataframe `df2` with `['n', 'u', 't', 'o']` as index, `['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4']` as columns name and the number of each `'n', 'u', 't', 'o'` per `sX`. So `df2['n', 's1']` is `2`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value_counts` of all columns with replace missing values to `0` and casting to integers:

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   s1  s2  s3  s4
n   2   3   0   1
o   0   0   7   0
t   2   2   0   2
u   3   2   0   4
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for Series with MultiIndex, then use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), but this is slowier in large `DataFrame`s:

```
df = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
L = list('notu')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(L, size=(N, 100))).add_prefix('s')
#print (df)
In [258]: %%timeit 
     ...: d=df.melt()
     ...: count_df=pd.crosstab(d['value'],d['variable'])
     ...: 
2.59 s ± 86.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [260]: %%timeit
     ...: df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
     ...: 
942 ms ± 43.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [262]: %%timeit
     ...: df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(0, fill_value=0)
     ...: 
10.9 s ± 547 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) + [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) is much faster 
in large data frames

```
d=df.melt()
count_df=pd.crosstab(d['value'],d['variable'])
print(count_df)

variable  s1  s2  s3  s4
value                   
n          2   3   0   1
o          0   0   7   0
t          2   2   0   2
u          3   2   0   4
```

Comment: `is much faster` - can you add some performance timings? Because I think you are wrong